# How to make Dask groupby return multiindex dataframe just like Pandas groupby

Tags: python, dask

Say I have a dataframe like

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,1,2,2,3,3], "Animal":["Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat","Dog","Cat"],
                   "Height":[1,2,1,2,1,2], "Name":["Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar"]
})
```

using pandas like this gives a multiindex return:

```py
df.groupby(["Id","Animal"],group_keys = True)[["Height","Name"]].apply(lambda x : x)
"""
             Height Name
Id Animal               
1  Cat    1       2  Bar
   Dog    0       1  Foo
2  Cat    3       2  Bar
   Dog    2       1  Foo
3  Cat    5       2  Bar
   Dog    4       1  Foo
"""
```

since my original dataframe has ~56mio rows I'm trying to use dask to speed it up, and it works fine! The issue is tho that I don't get a multiindex return result, I just get a dataframe with `["Height","Name"]`.

My dask-code is

```py
df_dd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
df_dd.groupby(["Id", "Animal"], group_keys=True)[["Height", "Name"]].apply(lambda x: x).compute()

"""
   Height Name
0       1  Foo
1       2  Bar
2       1  Foo
3       2  Bar
4       1  Foo
5       2  Bar
"""
```

I have tried specifying the `meta` object by

```py
df_meta = df.groupby(["Id","Animal"],group_keys = True)[["Height","Name"]].apply(lambda x : x)

df_dd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
df_dd.groupby(["Id", "Animal"], group_keys=True)[["Height", "Name"]].apply(lambda x: x, meta = df_meta).compute()
```

but that gives the same result.

Is there a way to get the same output as the pandas dataframe? Not knowing which group each value is in kinda ommits the entire "group-by" function.